# Truncation error creating clustered index on schema-bound view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was just creating a schema-bound view that I wanted to put an index on (to try out some computed column variations).

I created the view WITH SCHEMABINDING, then I had to create a clustered index before I could create my other non-clustered ones.

The underlying table has an INT primary key column, so I was going to make the view's clustered index based on that.  So I ran

```
Create UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [cix_viewEvents_EventID] ON [dbo].[viewEvents] (EventID)
```

Much to my surprise, after 4-5 minutes I got a

```
Msg 8152, string or binary data would be truncated
```

error.

The only column in the index is an int; what could be getting truncated?

I couldn't find anything relevant on google.

EDIT:

The original table is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
[EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[EventTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[EventContent] [varchar](max) NULL,
[EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EventID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

while the view I created looked like this

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.viewEvents
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT EventID, EventTitle, 
EventContent, EventDate, HASHBYTES('SHA1', EventContent) as ContentHash, HASHBYTES('SHA1', 
EventTitle) as TitleHash
from dbo.Events;
```

I was hoping to speed up comparisons on the title and content by having hashes to compare against instead of big blobs of text.

Rather than add the computed columns straight to the table, I thought I'd try the schema bound view first, but I ran into the "you need a clustered index on the view before you can create non-clustered indexes on it".  So I tried to create a clustered index, as noted above.

We're talking an int in both places, but creating the clustered index on the view  bombs with a truncation error, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure about clustered views, but when creating a clustered index, you're defining how to organize the whole data on a table. If a clustered view on an index does the same it's creating an structure with all columns that compose the view onganized by EventID. If that's correct you could be getting the error because of another column of the view. Are there other columns on that view? If possible, provide the view definition and the definition of the tables involved, they might be helpful to determine the error cause.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I edited the post to contain more of the ddl.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Did you notice that SHA1 is deprecated. And did you notice the restriction about the input size to HASHBYTES?

Comment: Stuck on Sql Server 2008 at the moment.  Thanks, I hadn't noticed the input length limit on HASHBYTES.

But this problem is before I get that far.

Comment: I was able to run your DDL without the error, so the problem is either related to your data on that table or to your version of SQL Server (I'm running a SQL Server 2019 instance). SMor pointed out something that is really relevant on the error you're getting. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) says **For SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and earlier, allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes.**. Can you query for a value bigger than that on your `[varchar](max)` columns?

Comment: Ah!  Sorry if I'm slow on the uptake, but is what you and SMor are saying is that to build the clustered index, sql server is *invoking* the view (hence dragging along the two HASHBYTES() columns - which would be susceptible to the HASHBYTES size limit)?

Okay, that makes some sense.  I was hung up on "how can an int get truncated?"

But if the index is being built by sifting over the results the view returns (even though those columns wouldn't be used), then I can see how the truncation error would happen.

Comment: I suspect that's what happening with your attempt to index the view, the data must be materialized. You could try casting your max columns to the smaller size to see if that works. But I just don't see the point of this view and how it "improves" anything.

Comment: There's this query that's looking for "duplicate" rows within the last 7 days, and it's taking a very long time comparing the title and the content.  I was interested in seeing if comparing the hashes would improve the performance.

At this point it's just a theory I want to run tests on.  There's replication set up on the table so I didn't want to actually change the underlying table's make-up to run the test.

I figured the indexed view would allow me to test in a way that I can just drop after without any impact on running processes.

Comment: I see. If you open a new question about how to improve that comparison, maybe a new solution will be achieved. I'd like to help with that, but I don't think discussing this other subject on the comments for this question is appropriate for the sake of organization :)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I have reposted the additional detail in a new question:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265277/speeding-up-duplicate-checks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The underlying table has an INT primary key column, so I was going to
>   make the view's clustered index based on that.

Here's what Microsoft says about [Create Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Creating a unique clustered index on a view improves query performance
>   because the view is stored in the database in the same way a table
>   with a clustered index is stored.

Since a clustered index is composed by data rows themselves your assumption that "the only column in the index is an int" is incorrect for, even though only one column was listed on the DDL, the clustered index view shall contain all columns under the hood. If it was a Nonclustered index, then only the listed columns would compose the index.

With the DDL you provided I was able to run some lab tests and the following chart from SSMS shall ilustrate my point:

[image: SQL Server chart]

As you can see, the view has pretty much the same size of the table. And before the index was created the view wouldn't even show on the chart. If it was formed only by the int column as you thought, it would have a much smaller size.

That info along with the contribution of [SMor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/140438/smor) about the limitation of [HASHBYTES Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) for SQL Server 2008:

> For SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and earlier, allowed input values are
>   limited to 8000 bytes.

In my lab I generated some data that was greater than 8000 bytes, but since I'm running a SQL Server 2019 instance, the DDL executed without any error. You can verify if you have any values that would exceed that limit with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM [dbo].[Events]
WHERE DATALENGTH([EventTitle]) > 8000
    OR DATALENGTH([EventContent]) > 8000;
```