# Speeding up "duplicate" checks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, query, index-tuning

We have an events table that is reasonably large (~35 million rows)

The original table is like this,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
[EventID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[EventTypeID] int,
[SourceID] int,
[EventTitle] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[EventContent] [varchar](max) NULL,
[EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([EventID] ASC)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and it has an index that looks like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_EventDate] ON [dbo].[Events] 
(
    [EventTypeID] ASC,
    [SourceID] ASC,
    [EventDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (EventTitle, EventContent)
```

When adding new events, there is a business requirement to check to see if there's a "duplicate" event filed within the last 7 days (duplicate defined as having the same title and content).  The above index is used in the check query, but it is still *very* slow and only rarely finds any duplicates.

The query looks like

```
SELECT *
FROM #NewEvents
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Events] e
    WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(dd, #NewEvents.EventXML.value('(/Event/EventDate)[1]', 'DATETIME'), e.EventDate) BETWEEN -7 AND 0
    AND e.EventTitle = #NewEvents.EventXML.value('(/Event/EventTitle)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
    AND e.EventContent = #NewEvents.EventXML.value('(/Event/EventContent)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
)
```

I had thought maybe a couple of computed columns with hashes on the title and content might speed the check (by making the indexes much more compact).  Not wanting to alter the underlying table on a theory (possibly mucking with the existing replication setup), I tried to create an indexed view with those computed columns.

I created an index on the view like the one above INCLUDING the computed columns, but for whatever reason I can't get the query to use that index on the view; it always defaults back to the base table index, and to make matters worse doesn't use the INCLUDE values for the computed values; it joins with the PK to fetch the original columns.

The view index looked like this (where TitleHash and ContentHash are HASHBYTES of the full column text)

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_viewEvents_EventDate] ON [dbo].[viewEvents] 
(
    [EventTypeID] ASC,
    [SourceID] ASC,
    [EventDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (TitleHash, ContentHash)
```

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions to speed up the query given the business constraints.

EDIT:  The first thing I tried was to change that DATEDIFF expression on the idea that it might have been blocking the use of the old index, but the plan for the old query showed that it was doing an Index Seek (not scan).

As Josh pointed out below, yeah the old query was doing an Index Seek - but only on the 2 leading columns.  The date was an output column and that filtering was done later.  But that stays that way no matter if I phrase the date filter as DATEDIFF() or "e.EventDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, #NewEvents.EventXML.value('(/Event/EventDate)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwNN.png)', 'DATETIME')) AND  #NewEvents.EventXML.value('(/Event/EventDate)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFwNN.png)', 'DATETIME')"

[image]

EDIT 2: Using WITH (NOEXPAND) did, indeed, get sql server to use the new view and the new index, though to my disappointment running the new view-based query and the old query in the same batch came back with the Actual Plan saying the view was 99% of the 2 query batch.  So the experiment doesn't appear to have been successful.  Changing the phrasing of the date filtering here, though, does seem to be reflected in the Index Seek node.

[image]

Comment: Are you awere of the fact that using a function like DATEDIFF  on a column of the predicate makes it not possible for SQL Server to use the index you configured?

Comment: Try to run your query like this: `SELECT *
FROM #NewEvents
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Events] e
    WHERE 
    e.EventDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
    AND e.EventTitle = #NewEvents.EventTitle
    AND e.EventContent = #NewEvents.EventContent
)` and see if it uses the idex you created.

Comment: you should make the key columns of the index `TitleHash, ContentHash, EventDate` so it can do an equality seek on the first two columns and then a range seek on the other column (which still needs to be written sargable-y)

Comment: Why does the execution plan have UDX XML operators and index seeks unrelated to the query you have shown us? The seek you have highlighted in the first plan doesn't seem related to the `WHERE EXISTS` and isn't against the index whose definition you have given

Comment: Depending on how the data is distributed, also consider doing an initial check for one value before checking if the other is also a duplicate. With a low number of hits and this could save a decent amount of I/O (i.e. see if Title / TitleHash matches, and only then check Conten / ContentHash)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I tried to simplify the example sometimes but may have left important details off the page.  The #NewEvents table actually gets the proposed new event information from an xml column.  That's being fished out to be used as search predicates against the existing table.  I figured it would be more straightforward in asking the question to not bother with that.

My thought was INCLUDING hashes vs raw text would make indexes a more compact and seeking faster - but the data would still be in the index, so how would breaking up title/content compares reduce i/o?

Comment: You should show your actual table structure, actual indexes, and actual query

Answer (score 4):

### Improving the Original Query

The query as written will *use* the nonclustered index that you created, but it won't *seek* into it - the whole index gets scanned.

I reproduced the query and data locally - the `DATEDIFF` version has a plan that looks like this:

[image]

```
Table 'Events'. Scan count 1, logical reads 28323

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1891 ms,  elapsed time = 1943 ms.
```

This plan will scan the `Events` table once for each row in your `#NewEvents` temp table.  It filters rows at the Nested Loops join operator after they've already been read.  This is not ideal.

To get a seek, you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #NewEvents
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Events] e
    WHERE 
    e.EventDate >= DATEADD(dd, -7, #NewEvents.EventDate)
    AND e.EventDate <= #NewEvents.EventDate
    AND e.EventTitle = #NewEvents.EventTitle
    AND e.EventContent = #NewEvents.EventContent
);
```

That plans looks like this:

[image]

```
Table 'Events'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 149 ms.
```

For each row in the temp table, there is a seek into your nonclustered index to just get the events that are within 7 days of the new event.  A filter is applied to qualifying rows to check if the title and content are equal.

The nice thing about this seek is that will, at most, read all the events within a 7 day span.  Which should be a fairly small number.

### Thoughts about the Indexed View

> I created an index on the view like the one above INCLUDING the computed columns, but for whatever reason I can't get the query to use that index on the view

I don't think the view is really necessary, if the change mentioned above provides reasonable performance.  But you could try adding a `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint after the view name in the query to see if you can force the view to be used.

Comment: Actually that was the first thing I tried as I thought the same thing but when I looked at the plan for the original query, it *did* show an Index Seek on that index even with the DATEDIFF formulation.

I've got a screen cap of the plan but I doubt the website will let me put it into a comment.

My hope with the view was that with the hashes included instead of the actual text, the index would be much more compact and more could be scanned per block resulting in fewer reads.

I'll try NOEXPAND, thanks.

Comment: @user1664043 You can edit your original post to add that screenshot.

Comment: @user1664043 "*Maybe those 2 columns in the front of the index was enough of a head start to get it to deal with the DATEDIFF?*" - if you hover over the index seek, you'll see that it was only able to seek on those first two fields.  It has to scan every row with that pair of EventTypeId, SourceId and check the dates individually.

Comment: I see what you mean, but am still a little puzzled comparing the plans.  Either way I phrase the EventDate part, the old query/index shows the Output List as Title, Content and Event Date (with the date filtering done later).  It also has a Seek Predicate section showing type and source being checked against the index

Comment: When I vary the date part of the query on the view, using DATEDIFF() shows the date being evaluated in the Predicate section of that plan node, the Output List section with the title and content hashes, and the Seek Predicate section being on type and source.  But when change the date filter to >= DATEADD(), the Predicate and Seek Predicate sections of that node simply go away.  It just has the Object being the index, and the output list being the hashes.

Comment: Looking at the broader view of the plans, as written, I see the title, content and, date as the outputs of the index seek.

The next outer nodes are both hash merges on the title and content, *then* the date gets evaluated.  I guess Sql Server is figuring that = is more selective than a range.

I found that if I rephrased the query as an INNER JOIN with the type, source and date in the ON clause, then I could get sql server to evaluate the date as part of the index seek.

Haven't gotten a chance to run the numbers yet to see if it helps performance